# Similarity of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I'm looking for a method that takes two simple polynomials (cubic) and gives a value of how visually-similar they are to each other on some specified domain. How could I do this?

Comment: Define "visually similar"

Comment: You would have to come up with a more rigorous definition of what it means for them to be visually similar.  For example, is it a point-by-point comparison?

Comment: Graphing the two polynomials?

Comment: Two comparisons I can see are (for polynomials $f(x),g(x)$): $f(x)-g(x)$, $f(x)\over g(x)$. It depends on what you want to compare...

Comment: If you want one value, then perhaps a suitable norm of their difference could be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Cubic polynomials have three roots. They may be all real, or two of them may be a conjugate pair of complex numbers. You could translate the polynomials into the following form:

$$p_1(x) = A_1(x - r_{11})(x - r_{12})(x - r_{13})$$
$$p_2(x) = A_2(x - r_{21})(x - r_{22})(x - r_{23})$$

Depending on your definition of "visually similar" you could disregard the scaling factors $A_1$ and $A_2$. Another simplification would be to shift the polynomials in such a way, that the smallest real root is zero. The distance between polynomials would then be something like 
$$| r_{12} - r_{22}| + |r_{13} - r_{23}|$$

Select the ordering of the roots such that the difference is minimized.

Comment: It seems that this wouldn't work for comparisons such as this, where the imaginary and normal roots are being compared: https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&hl=en&ei=A6FZUvWaLInO9QTW3oCwDg&q=x%5E3-2x%5E2-3x%2B5%2C+x%5E3-2x%5E2-3x%2B7&oq=x%5E3-2x%5E2-3x%2B5%2C+x%5E3-2x%5E2-3x%2B7&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...12700.14550.0.15215.2.2.0.0.0.0.900.1216.3-1j6-1.2.0....0...1c.1.28.mobile-gws-serp..2.0.0.knJvzKFDRWw

Comment: To improve the comparison, you could add a distance measure of the roots of the first derivatives.