# Area Between Polynomials as a Similarity Measure?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I'm trying to find a conceptually easy way to calculate a "similarity" number between two polynomials. The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522161/similarity-of-polynomials) compares the roots of each polynomial, but it isn't obvious to me how you would deal with complex roots.

My question is whether you can simply use the total area (not the net area) between the two polynomials over a fixed domain, as a rough measure of how similar they are?

I can't seem to find any resources that explicitly show how to compare polynomials. Things that mentions it seem to skip over how it's actually done.

**Edit:** If the area is not a good measure, are there any other appropriate techniques that I'm not aware of?

Comment: The area is not a good measure. Think of $x$ and $x+a$. The area between these two (very similar) polynomials depends very much  on $a$.

Comment: @zoli For the project I'd like to use this in, I already have to normalize all my data to fit into a particular range. I would hope that gets rid of most issues with polynomials only differing by some scale factor or vertical translation, although I certainly could be mistaken.